# Phpstorm : working with git branches and remote deployment

Tags: git, phpstorm, git-branch

I have a PhpStorm project linked to a remote server (a VM) where I set automatic deployment, so each time I modify and save a file, it is uploaded automatically to this server.
Now I want to use GIT on this project.
My workflow should be the following :
- Work on local copy 
- Saving and automatic upload to the development server
- Test (open webpage on dev server)
- if ok, commit from local copy. Then push, etc...

My question is : how to work with branches ? I mean, I know that when switching branch, the directory I work on can completely change. 
Example : my branch A contains a.html. My branch B only contains b.html
If I switch branch locally, the content of my folder will change. Will PhpStorm will add/delete a.html/b.html on my deployment server each time I switch branch ? Obviously, it's not what I want. 
How these changes will be reflected on the deployment server, how PhpStorm manage it ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: (not an expert in VCS+Deployment here) Automatically: unlikely (even if it does: it potentially may create a mess). Better do it manually (I would): `Tools | Deployment | Sync with Deployed...`. In any case: there are few settings for automatic deployment in  `Settings | Deployment | Options` (AFAIK the VCS operations are considered "external activities" so you should check that option).

Comment: Ok so PhpStorm doesn't offer a real solution for that kind of situation. To be able to test each branch, I'll have to upload in any case to the deployment server (so in different remote folder). To do so, I'll have to create a deployment server for each branch, and choose on which server I deploy ? Is it the best solution ?

Comment: Sorry -- cannot really help here (not using VCSs myself ;( ). But .. if deployment for each branch has to be made into a different folder .. then yes -- either create multiple deployment entries and switch between them (or choose manually which one to use when manually syncing) .. or alter your default deployment entry each time (change target folder). As you can see there is no automation in this regard. If deployment will be made into the same folder -- then I do not really see any issues here (unless I've got you wrong).

Comment: Ok, if there's no automation or no better solution, I will opt for creating deployment entries each time I create a branch. But thinking back, I wonder if having a remote folder that changes all the time is really a problem, as long as I can test by opening my browser and have a fully functional environment. Any other suggestion is welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone is looking for the solution:

```
Tools > Deployment > Options
```

Uncheck `Skip external changes`

***Please Note:*** Option `Automatic Upload (always)` must be checked

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, you can approach a number of different ways. Here's a couple.

1. set up a cron job on the server to regularly pull from master, then you would have to use branches for each new task and merge them when they are done, and the cron job will handle it on next pull of master.
2. if you prefer to handle this in phpstorm, you can create a bash alias in your .bashrc or .bash_profile to ssh into the server and do a pull (I named my alias 'deploy'), then you can run the command in the built in terminal in phpstorm.

I prefer the second method as I don't have to wait for cron to do it's thing and I can see when an error occurs such as a merge conflict of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem having an ssh window open with the remote environment. Just create a branch and do a checkout on the remote server. Now all the changes you upload via phpstorm will count as changes to that branch. You can still save and then view the results in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

From [a Jetbrains support community post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206357639/comments/360002693640):

> You can utilize synchronous repository control:
>
> Init a repo in the .idea folder, add the same branches as you have in
> the main repo, and add the corresponding deployment.xml to them. So
> your project will have 2 repos - the main one with code, that is
> shared, and the local one with your .idea/deployment (and other
> configs if needed).
>
> Make sure the repo in the .idea folder is correctly recognized in the
> IDE, add a mapping in Settings | Version Control. Then enable Execute
> git operations on all branches in Settings | Version Control | Git.
>
> This way, along with switching branch in the main repo the version of
> deployment.xml will be also switched.

I tested this and it works well. You have to set up the repo in .idea with the same branches as your main repo and do the settings as described. Commit both versions of the deployment.xml file in the .idea repo.
When switching branches the .idea repo branch is switched too. The only caveat is that you have to use the PHPStorm Git Branches window to switch both at the same time. Switching via git checkout in the Terminal does not work for that. I find that not so handy when you are used to using the terminal. The switch via the Git Branches window is not visible in the Terminal, so you get confused quickly about which branch is checked out.

More info:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/08/git-branches-for-multi-root-projects/
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manage-branches.html#synchronous_branch_control

Answer (score -1):

PHPStorm's GIT will only use your local copy. This hasn't anything to do with deployment. PHPStorm should not commit his own configuration files within the project. You can check this at `Settings -> Version Control -> Ignored Files` where it should say the `.idea` folder and a file ending with `.iws`. Ofcourse you could also add other files to ignore (like your own config files)

If you're using git in the CLI (not in PHPStorm) you should create a .gitignore file containing to ignore PHPStorm's config files:

```
/.idea
*.iws
```

PHPStorm should only sync branch-switches when `Upload external changes` is enabled in the deployment options since GIT is external.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but it's not really what I asked for. The main problem I see is when I switch branch. My branch A contains a file a.html. I switch on my branch B, which only contains b.html. Will it synchronize with my remote server each time and change the content of my folder there ?